# Confluence REST API: HTTP 200 w/ Empty Response

Tags: curl, response, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I cannot seem to create a new page on Confluence Cloud v1000.957.0 via the Rest API. I have tried both using cURL and Python to no avail: all I get back is `HTTP 200` with an empty JSON response every time. If I change the credentials to be incorrect, I get `HTTP 401`.

```
curl -u ******@******.com:****** -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"TESTING123", "ancestors":[{"id":123456}], "space":{"key":"AA"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' https://********.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/
```

I have changed a few details of the cURL call for the sake of anonymity, but I know the credentials, ancestor ID, space key, and API URL are correct. I have also verified that this account has the correct permissions in Confluence to create a page in this space, and that API access for Confluence is enabled.

Variations on the API call that I have tried:

1. Adding `?os_authType=basic` to the end of the URL
2. Adding as many parameters as possible (all with empty values) such as:

   - `status: current`
   - `operations: []`
   - `metadata: {}`
3. Changing the API call to create a page at the top level within the Confluence space (omitting the `ancestors` field).
4. Adding this header: `Accept: application/json`
5. Adding the `view` option to the `body` portion of the call and subsequently appending this to the end of the URL: `&expand=body.view`. I have found that adding it to the Python code gives the same result, but adding it to the cURL call prints out something like `[1] 42999` (the latter part changes with each call); then upon a new command or simply upon pressing `Return`, it prints `[1]+ Done` followed by a chunk of whitespace, then the cURL call I just made.

I found a very similar bug in Atlassian's JIRA for JIRA software, so apparently this happens for JIRA as well, but intermittently.
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-41559

I'm not terribly familiar with HTTP protocol, so there may be something I am overlooking, so really I just want more options to try (although a solution would be ideal, of course).

Comment: Did you succeed to retrieve a list of existing contents or to use other API requests? Try to call some API requests via your browser (GETs just via url, POSTs with a browser extension, e.g. [YARC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yet-another-rest-client/ehafadccdcdedbhcbddihehiodgcddpl)) to differ between authentication and request problems.

Comment: I didn't, but I did manage to get it working by omitting the username's domain in the cURL call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using username with domain as credentials (******<strike>@******.com</strike>:******)

You can check if this is working just by asking for main wiki content.
Try:
`curl -u <user>:<pass> https://<domain>.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/`

You can also ommit password. Curl will ask for it - it's safer from security perspective.
Try:
`curl -u <user> https://<domain>.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/`

Comment: There actually is an [issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-41704?src=confmacro) on this problem, but Atlassian says it is resolved.

Comment: @lukegv: Difference being that now we do not even get `401:unauthorized`. Instead we get `HTTP 200` with empty reposponse (no JSON) and HTTP header field `X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK` which seems to state that _Login is OK_.

Comment: @maciej
This is what I get if I remove the domain from the user name. There isn't a `b` in the content I'm trying to post, so unless it's a weird encoding issue, I don't think it's coming from the content I'm trying to post.

`{"statusCode":500,"message":"org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('b' (code 98)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false'
 or 'null')\n at [Source: com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.restapi.filters.LimitingRequestFilter$1@1097e3e; line: 1, column: 2]"}`

Comment: @maciej Sorry, that's what I got when I did that in Python. It works in cURL, though! I'll tinker with my Python implementation to see if I can get that to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: The reason I was getting a 500 was because I forgot to encode the Python dict as JSON data: I was passing it the raw dict. Rectified thusly: `json.dumps(data)`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who ends up here... I had this exact problem where a `r = requests.get(URL, auth=(USER, PASSWORD)` to a URL that was a wiki page .../wiki/rest/api/content/123454 would have a 200 r.status_code and r.text was empty.

Fix is to use requests.session() and make two calls. One (I assume) to establish the session and the second to get the content.

```
s = requests.session()
s.auth = (USER, PASSWORD)
r = s.get(url_base) # url_base = '.../wiki/rest/api'
r = s.get(url) # url = '.../wiki/rest/api/content/123453'
```

then r.text will have content.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving my crazy as well. My solution was finally found by creating a session. Not sure exactly how to do this using cURL. May have to use PHP or something. I used NodeJS

What's going on here is XSRF tokens are being sent out when you make your first request. You need a session to store these. Once stored, they must be sent out with all subsequent requests.

My application was written in NodeJS. YMMV in other languages, but the following worked for me:

```
var request = require('request');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var cookieJar = request.jar(); // <-- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART

  var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://test.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content',
  jar: cookieJar,
  headers:
   {'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     authorization: 'Basic yourBase64AuthToken' } };

  // You'll need to make two requests, one to get the tokens,
  // and another to actually get your query to work
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log(body);
    });
  });

res.send('hello');
});
```